# Can't access server from device, works in emulator

Tags: android

Seems like everyone have issue accessing local machine or internet etc from emulator. All that works for me. Now I got my WCF service installed on my home server, port opened and I can browse just fine with a browser.

I changed URL in emulator, pointed to "real" server and it WORKS. Now, I installed app on device and it times out connecting to server (10 seconds). What do I miss?

Server is IIS7.5 with .NET WCF REST service. Device connected to 3G and I can browse my own site from web browser on device but in code it fails. Code looks like so and my url like "http://domain:8080/mobile/auth"

EDIT: Tried on another phone and it WORKS! What can be a problem? My phone is Nexus S with 2.3, I target 2.2 and my emulator 2.2 And my other phone (which works) also 2.2

Also, one phone on TMobile and another on Sprint. Is that weird issue?

EDIT 2:
Some Google search.. It might be related to T-Mobile blocking port 8080. I do post specifically and when I browse via browser it does GET, so maybe my issue there. I will try on another T-Mobile phone tomorrow.

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

        try
        {
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(requestData);
            entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            request.setEntity(entity);
            ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            returnData = client.execute(request, handler);
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            String s = e.getMessage();
            //TODO: Log exception on device
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure looks like you answered your own question there:

```
//TODO: Log exception on device
```

If you're not getting an exception, then it sounds very much like a DNS problem. Try connecting to your local network via wifi and see if that eliminates the problem.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I do get exception, I run it through debugger. Exception is: java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Comment: Hm. What I do to fix it now? I connected to WiFi and it works. like I posted on main question - other phone works as-is. Is that T-Mobile? Or my device?

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified your device has internet connectivity? I know it sounds silly, but I've been having some real problems today with my Nexus S running 2.3.3.

Try opening a browser and navigating to a non-cached page.

Comment: I have same phone :) First thing I checked - I opened browser on my phone and navigated to site. It worked. Actually.. I have another phone I can try..

Comment: I see your post below - tmobile has been terrible for me today...I've been trying to test my admob integration and my network issues are being a pain.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. On that same phone I go to browser and access same url just fine.

Comment: My wifes G2 works just fine as expected. Only my Nexus S acts up and only when on 3G. That is strange..